# Listar datos que están asociados a una tabla intermedia

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Tengo la siguiente relación, donde `NOTICIA_FOTOS` es una tabla intermedia entre `NOTICIA` y `FOTOS`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo quiero obtener una lista datos de la tabla `FOTOS` a través una `NOTICIA`. La forma como lo estoy haciendo *por el momento* es almacenar el resultado en un `ViewData`, usando el siguiente código de mi método del `Controller`:

```
Dim fotos As FOTO = (From t3 In db.FOTO From intermedia In t3.NOTICIA.Where(Function(x) x.IdNoticia = 22))
        ViewData("nombre_fotos") = fotos.NombreFoto
```

Necesito obtener solamente los nombres de las fotos de una noticia; pero al ejecutar el código me sale el siguiente error:

```
No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[VB$AnonymousType_0`2 ........
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener correctamente los resultados de la consulta de la tabla `FOTOS` a través del `IdNoticia`?, ¿en este caso sería una lista?

Comment: Ambos campos de ID en NOTICIA_FOTOS son "IdFotos"?

Comment: Puedes colocar el error completo sin cortarlo?

Comment: Además puedes colocar la definición de las clases que corresponde a las entidades?

Comment: disculpa, una es IdFotos y el otro es IdNoticia

Comment: el error completo es :
Additional information: No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[VB$AnonymousType_0`2[IMPCHLosCopihues_MVC.FOTO,IMPCHLosCopihues_MVC.NOTICIA]]' al tipo 'IMPCHLosCopihues_MVC.FOTO'.

 Uso entity framework

Comment: Partial Public Class FOTO
    Public Property IdFoto As Integer
    Public Property NombreFoto As String
    Public Property FechaFoto As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property FormatoFoto As String
    Public Property Foto As Byte()
    Public Overridable Property NOTICIA As ICollection(Of NOTICIA) = New HashSet(Of NOTICIA)
End Class

Comment: Partial Public Class NOTICIA
    Public Property IdNoticia As Integer
    Public Property Rut As String
    Public Property TituloNoticia As String
    Public Property DescripcionNoticia As String
    Public Property FechaPublicacionNoticia As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property FotoPortadaNoticia As Byte()
    Public Property NombreFotoPortadaNoticia As String
    Public Property FormatoFotoPortadaNoticia As String

    Public Overridable Property FOTO As ICollection(Of FOTO) = New HashSet(Of FOTO)
End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que la tabla `NOTICIA_FOTOS` es un mapeo asociativo, tus `POCOs` serían parecidos a los siguientes:

```
public class Noticia
{
    public int IdNoticia{ get; set; }
    public string Noticia{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Foto> Fotos { get; set; }
}

public class Foto
{
    public int IdFoto { get; set; }
    public string NombreFoto{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Noticia> Noticias{ get; set; }
}
```

Deberías poder obtener las fotos a través del `IdNoticia` así:

```
From n In db.Noticia & _
Where n.IdNoticia = x & _
From f In n.Fotos & _
Select New With {
    .IdFoto = f.IdFoto, 
    .NombreFoto = f.NombreFoto, 
    .IdNoticia = n.IdNoticia
}
```

Comment: Si la query la almaceno asi;

Dim fotos  = From n In db.NOTICIA Where n.IdNoticia = 22 From f In
 n.FOTO Select New With {.IdFoto = f.IdFoto, .NombreFoto =
 f.NombreFoto, .IdNoticia = n.IdNoticia}

 y si quiero mostrar la query en el ViewData, ViewData("nombre_fotos") = fotos, me lanza error en la vista, en el mismo ViewData que se debería mostrar datos:
 La instancia de ObjectContext se ha desechado y ya no se puede usar para operaciones que requieren una conexión.

Comment: ¿Estás usando la consulta dentro de un `using`? Ese error casi siempre se debe a que has cerrado o descartado el contexto y luego has vuelto a usarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando defines el modelo de entity framework entiendo que estas entidades estan relacionadas muchos a muchos, no ? usas un edmx o code first

Quizas la query de linq deberia ser directa, como ser:

```
Dim noticia As Noticia = db.NOTICIA.Include("FOTOS").FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.IdNoticia = 22)

If noticia IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim fotos As List(Of FOTO) = noticia.FOTOS
End If
```

saludos

Comment: Esto genera dos consultas SQL cuando la expresión puede realizarse en una sola.

Comment: hola Carlos, si es verdad lo que comentas es que olvide un detalle, definir el Include()  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx  si se indica podria recuperar las fotos sin aplicar lazy load

Comment: Si,uso entidades relacionada muchos a muhos. Uso edmx